# Unity3D - Shader Graph - Where did the definition parameter go?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader-graph

Since I updated unity's universal render pipeline I can't find the definition parameter for the boolean property in shader graph. I want to set the parameter "definition" to multi compile but it has just disappeared. Can anyone help me find it again? :) Or did unity change how it works?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it seems your before picture is depicting a Boolean Keyword, whereas the After is a Properties Boolean. When pressing the + in the shader graph, look at the bottom to find the option to add a Keyword.